# Drupal move from subdirectory

Tags: php, drupal, installation, move, subdirectory

I had a drupal site completely working at www.example.com/example. I copied the files to the root folder in attempt to simply have the site held at www.example.com yet now it is asking for a new install and I have no idea why, I expected to have to make some changes, but not to be confronted with the request of a new install. I have heard it may be something to do with changing the base url but I'm not sure.  Can someone please help me?

Thanks heaps

Comment: Did you change out the location of Database configuration file.. In `sites/default/settings.php`

Comment: Cheers, the site at least stops asking for new install. But now it is showing only basic images with no menu etc. Any ideas?

Comment: No menus means.. no `menu tab` created till now.

Comment: Yeah!, you need to create menus.. And did you previously made out `menus`

Comment: Well I had menus and all before but now nothing.

Comment: so did you check out with Database configuration file

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your site is on a linux based hosting, most probably your problem is divided into two parts

Problem 1) The settings file "sites/default/settings.php" is read only so when you moved the site to another directory it most probably didn't move this file because it is read only, and that was pointed out by another person

Problem 2) The second problem may be the result of enabling clean urls and not moving .htaccess file; when you moved the site to another directory you may have left out the ".htaccess". Check to see if it is moved to the new directory.

Another possibility is that you have a modified .htaccess to make the subdirectory work, in that case you may want to get a fresh ".htaccess" file from here : 
http://code.google.com/p/drupalgooglecode/source/browse/trunk/.htaccess